# Is it possible to launch a fancybox iframe on page load?

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I have googled "[**fancybox, open onload**](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=cr&ei=jA0rUtHsBJL44QSOr4HwCA#q=fancybox%2C%20open%20onload)" all afternoon, but none of the answers seems to match what I'm trying to do. My fancybox set-up works like this:
[**www.casedasole.it/fancybox/**](http://www.casedasole.it/fancybox/index.html)
i.e. it launches an iframe.

The [**fancybox website**](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) gives two examples of `Launch fancyBox on page load` (point 10), but in both cases it's handling images.

The box I want to appear is an **iframe** with text, and links in it open within the iframe.
I found a way of opening onload a hidden div as a fancybox window (see [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/webdevem/5EV8r/)). I got that to work - [**www.casedasole.it/fancybox/ok.html**](http://www.casedasole.it/fancybox/ok.html) - in fact it combines both ways of launching the iframe content - as a pop-up hidden div in the launch page, and also from that page's launch button, which launches the actual iframe (close the div-generated window to see).

BUT, what opens onload is not an iframe - so any links within it will open a new page.

So, anybody know if it's possible to launch a fancybox **iframe** onload? I get the feeling it's not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simple. You just need to specify the type of content you want to open using the `type` API option like

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        type: "iframe" // <-- whatever content : image, inline, swf, etc.
    }).trigger("click");
}); // ready
```

**Notice** we chained the `.fancybox()` and `.trigger()` methods.

The code above assumes you have this html somewhere in your page :

```
<a class="fancybox" href="http://example.com">this link open external page on an iframe</a>
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8qp0Lr3z/)**

---

Another option, if you don't want to have a link to the page as in the example above, is to trigger fancybox programmatically like :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $.fancybox({
        href: "http://example.com",
        type: "iframe" // <-- whatever content image, inline, swf, etc
    });
}); // ready
```

**Notice** that in this case, you need to pass the URL of the page you want to open using the `href` API option.

See updated **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8qp0Lr3z/1/)**