# Fancybox iframe with content encoded in js on launch page - how to open on page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

Thanks to [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26366516/is-it-possible-to-launch-a-fancybox-iframe-on-page-load), I have a way of launching a fancybox iframe on page-load: http://www.casedasole.it/fancybox/A.html

[**This answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11678956/fancybox-displaying-contents-of-a-div-as-type-iframe) shows how to open a fancybox iframe whose content is encoded in javascript in the page that launches the iframe: http://www.casedasole.it/fancybox/B.html

Is there some way of having B do what A does - i.e. launch itself on page-load?

NB: The hidden div approach ([see here](http://www.casedasole.it/fancybox/ok.html)) won't work because I need to be able to navigate within the iframe once opened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do :

```
var myContent = "..."; // html as option "B"

jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $.fancybox({
        // API options as "B"
        // build the iframe
        content: '<iframe id="myFrame" class="fancybox-iframe" frameborder="0" vspace="0" hspace="0" src="about:blank"></iframe>',
        afterShow: function () {
            var oIframe = document.getElementById('myFrame');
            var iframeDoc = (oIframe.contentWindow.document || oIframe.contentDocument);
            iframeDoc.open();
            iframeDoc.write(myContent);
            iframeDoc.close();
        }
    });
}); // ready
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mLq9oywt/)**

**Notice** the `myContent` variable contains the **full** `html` structure, including `DOCTYPE`, `<html>`, `<head>` an `<body>` sections. Although it's not mandatory, it will give you more control over the settings of your initial (iframed) page.

Also notice in my *jsfiddle* I separated the base content (`html` basic structure) from the custom content (the `<div>` as in your example) for tidiness purposes ;)

Refs :

- Option A : http://jsfiddle.net/8qp0Lr3z/1/
- Option B : http://jsfiddle.net/qVrLr/

Comment: Thanks, does the job: http://www.gattapelata.it/fbox/  But one problem - how to prevent the iframe being closed by a click on the overlay? If I use modal: true, the close-click is blocked, but the close "X" (fancybox_sprite.png) disappears as well.

Comment: I got it: afterLoad: function () {
 $('.fancybox-skin').append('<a title="Close" class="fancybox-item fancybox-close" href="javascript:jQuery.fancybox.close();"></a>');
 }, - don't know why but, with modal:true, that fixes the problem

Comment: @plugincontainer closing fancybox after clicking the overlay is the default behavior but can change it like http://stackoverflow.com/a/8404587/1055987 If `modal` is set to `true`,  it will disable navigation and closing default buttons

Comment: helpers : { overlay : {closeClick: false}}, worked too. Thanks again!