# How to include javascript tags in a javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox, fancybox-2

Building on the [**answer to this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26673658/fancybox-iframe-with-content-encoded-in-js-on-launch-page-how-to-open-on-page) (see [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mLq9oywt/)), I have:

```
var baseContent = '<!DOCTYPE html><html lang=\"en\"><head><title>..etc...</head><body>'+myContent+'</body></html>';
```

...and it works (produces the content of an iframe, in this case). However, if I use the same procedure to add some javascript in the `<head>` (or `<body>`), e.g.:

```
<script type=\"text/javascript\">swfobject.embedSWF(\"flash.swf\", \"my_flash\");</script>
```

...I get error `unterminated string literal` at `var baseContent = '`.   How do I include javascript in `var baseContent`?

**update**

@TamarG I tried the suggestions below but no luck - see: http://www.casedasole.it/fancybox/js/index.html. I need to include in `var baseContent` both a link to an external javascript file (swobject.js) and its related  javascript in the `<head>`. But adding `<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"swfobject.js\"></script>` to `var baseContent` stops the iframe loading, with the same error: `unterminated string literal` at `var baseContent = '`.

**Explanation** (reply to below)

The [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mLq9oywt/) referred to in my question shows how fancybox can be used to open an iframe on page-load. The content of the iframe is encoded in the "launch" page (unusual, because usually fancybox iframes load a separate HTML file, image, video etc).

In the JSFiddle example, `var baseContent` contains a sample of HTML that can be used to create the iframe content (`<!DOCTYPE>`, `<head>`, `<style>` `<body>`, etc). Encoding the basic HTML in `var baseContent` looks easy - e.g. `<style type="text/css">` becomes `<style type=\"text/css\">`.

But I also need the iframe `<head>` to link to an external swfobject.js file and to include the standard 2-line swfobject flash detection script, `swfobject.embedSWF("flash.swf", "my_flash"`, etc.

But when I use the same approach that works with the other HTML tags to encode the javascript tags, i.e. encode `<script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"></script>` as `<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"swfobject.js\"></script>`, there is an error and the iframe won't open on page-load - [see this page](http://www.casedasole.it/fancybox/js/index+js.html).

So my question is how to format links to external js files in `var baseContent` (and then, once that's working, how to format js in the `var baseContent` itself).

Comment: Try replacing `</script>` with `<\/script>`.  Tweaking the HTML so that it doesn't contain a close script tag will let you embed it within JavaScript embedded in an HTML script element.

Comment: To include your scripts tags within a variable (e.g. `baseContent="{html code}"`) you have to do like `<\script src=\"http://example.com/swfobject.js\"><\/script>`. See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/45cy0h63/1/)**. If you analyze the contents of the iframe, you'll notice the scripts were perfectly loaded within the iframe. **Note**: I would advice you to set **absolute** paths for your included *.js* files since the iframe is created in the DOM and may not have reference of relative paths. If the question is re-opened, I could post this as an answer.

Comment: Further more you can include full functionality inside the iframe and call external stylesheets and js files by adding the respective `<link />` and `<script></script>` tags inside the js variable: http://jsfiddle.net/72k79hc0/

Comment: @JFK Got it working: http://www.casedasole.it/fancybox/js/ok.html (I now know that in var myContent my " should be '). Thanks for the answer, hope they re-open the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<script type=\"text/javascript\">` is to enter JS in html. if the main code is JS - just remove `<script type=\"text/javascript\"></script>` and write only `swfobject.embedSWF("flash.swf", "my_flash");`

```
'<!DOCTYPE html><html lang=\"en\"><head><title>'+
swfobject.embedSWF("flash.swf", "my_flash")
+'</head><body>'+myContent+'</body></html>';
```

Comment: Anyone else stuck with formatting html in javascript, there's this: https://www.freeformatter.com/javascript-escape.html - saved me a lot of time.